# Preencher uma Listbox com Banco de Dados Paradox(Delphi)

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, lista, tabela-html

Boa tarde, amigos. Estou tendo dificuldades para preencher uma listbox com informações de uma tabela de Banco de Dados em Paradox, O Data Source é o arquivo "Gap03Dm.SourceChaves" e o DataField é "Campo". COmo fazer?

Comment: Eu tenho pena de ti de ter que trabalhar com um banco desses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TFrmPrincipal.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  Table1.First;
  while not Table1.Eof do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Table1.FieldByName('CAMPO').AsString);
    Table1.Next;
  end;
end;
```